# CUDA "unspecified launch failure" accessing memory

Tags: memory, cuda, runtime-error

what i'm trying to do is very simple.
each thread reads sub-array from global array stored in the global memory.
then it do some calculations and store the result in static array.
at last the output is stored back in another array in global memory
when i comment the line which writes the static array to the global array the kernel run.as shown in the code.
any ideas?

GPU kernel :

```
#ifndef _TEMPLATE_KERNEL_H_
#define _TEMPLATE_KERNEL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

__device__  void
DecompressBlockGPU(unsigned char *compressed_block,unsigned char *compressed_size,
                    int array_length,unsigned char *decompressed_block)
{       
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < array_length ;i++)
    {
        for(int idx = 0 ; idx < compressed_size[i]; idx++)
        {
            decompressed_block[j] = compressed_block[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
__global__ void

gpu_test(unsigned char *compressed_data,int *OffsetsArray,int xBlocks,int yBlocks,
        unsigned char *output, int BlockSize,int BlockWidth,int BlockHeight,
        int cols,int xTB,int yTB,int xTH,int yTH,unsigned char *aux_array)
{
    int x_max = xBlocks ;
    int y_max = yBlocks ;

    int x_block = blockIdx.x ; 
    int y_block = blockIdx.y ;

    x_max = gridDim.x*blockDim.x ;
    y_max = gridDim.y*blockDim.y ;

    x_block = (blockIdx.x*xTH); 
    y_block = (blockIdx.y*yTH);
    int x_block1 = x_block + threadIdx.x;
    int y_block1 = y_block + threadIdx.y;

    int block_idx = y_block1*xBlocks + x_block1;
    unsigned char *temp_ptr = compressed_data + OffsetsArray[block_idx];        
    int *array_length = (int *)temp_ptr;
    unsigned char *compressed_size = compressed_data + OffsetsArray[block_idx] + 
                               array_length[0] +sizeof(int)/sizeof(unsigned char);
    unsigned char *compressed_block = compressed_data + OffsetsArray[block_idx] + 
                               sizeof(int)/sizeof(unsigned char);

    aux_array = aux_array + (BlockWidth+2)*(BlockHeight+2)*block_idx;
    aux_array[block_idx]=array_length[0];

    unsigned char decompressed_block[72];
    unsigned char extracted_block[32];

    DecompressBlockGPU(compressed_block,compressed_size,array_length[0],
                             &decompressed_block[0]);

    if(block_idx == 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++) aux_array[i]= decompressed_block[i]; //fails  
        for(int i=16;i<16*36;i++) aux_array[i]=1;//works
    }
}
#endif
```

CPU functions :

```
unsigned char *runGPU(unsigned char *d_compressed_data,int *OffsetsArray,int xBlocks,int yBlocks,unsigned char *h_output)
{


    printf("xBlocks =%d yBlocks =%d  \n",xBlocks,yBlocks);



    int xTB = 4;
    int yTB = 4;
    int xTH = 1;
    int yTH = 1; 



    unsigned char *d_output;
    unsigned char *d_aux_array;
    unsigned char *h_aux_array;

    int mem_size = image_len*sizeof(unsigned char);
    int big_mem_size = sizeof(unsigned char)*xBlocks*yBlocks*(BlockWidth+2)*(BlockHeight+2);

    cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_output, mem_size));
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_aux_array,big_mem_size));
    h_aux_array = (unsigned char *)malloc(big_mem_size);


    float time = 0;
    float totalTime = 0;
    cudaEvent_t start_event4, stop_event4;
    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventCreate(&start_event4) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventCreate(&stop_event4) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventRecord(start_event4, 0) );

    dim3 grid(xTB,yTB, 1);
    dim3 threads( xTH, yTH, 1);

    gpu_test<<<grid,threads>>>(d_compressed_data,OffsetsArray,xBlocks,yBlocks,d_output,BlockSize,BlockWidth,BlockHeight,cols,xTB,yTB,xTH,yTH,d_aux_array);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventRecord(stop_event4, 0) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventSynchronize(stop_event4) );
    time = 0;
    cutilSafeCall( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start_event4, stop_event4));
    totalTime += time;
    totalTime /= (1.0e3 * 1);
    shrLogEx(LOGBOTH | MASTER, 0, "GPU decompression Time = %.5f \n",totalTime); 

    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(h_output,d_output, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(h_aux_array,d_aux_array, big_mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    cudaFree(d_output);
    cudaFree(d_aux_array);

    return h_aux_array;

}
```

is it clear now ?(after editing)

Comment: Could you edit the question to include some *meaningful* code? From  What you have posted it is absolutely impossible to say anything about what might be wrong. Post concise, compilable code which reproduces the problem and then you might get some useful suggestions.

Comment: Not more details, different details. You are asking about a runtime error, and yet the code you have posted cannot be compiled or run, so there is not much anyone can do to help you.

Comment: I agree with talonmies: Resolving this kind of issue requires a self-contained repro case. In very generic terms, an ULF is the equivalent of a segfault on a CPU, i.e. you probably have an out of bounds memory access somewhere in your kernel.

Comment: To chime in with @talonmies, reducing the problem to the simplest case that triggers the bug is a good debugging technique anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try running your program through [cuda-memcheck](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html) (or enable memory checking if you are using Parallel Nsight).